# Create automatically from "*.coffee" "*.coffee.js" instead of "*.js"

Tags: coffeescript, command-line-interface

I use:

```
> coffee -c myscript.coffee
```

And in output I have *myscript.js*. I want to have *myscript**.coffee**.js*. Is there possibility to do it with help of coffee cli only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you can't do it solely through the CoffeeScript CLI. However, with a little Unix magic:

```
coffee -p -c myscript.coffee > myscript.coffee.js
```

Comment: "coffee -p -c myscript.coffee > myscript.coffee.js" -- great! thanks. And if I want to do it with *.coffee? To create *.coffee.js

Comment: Happy to help. Would you mind accepting my answer? :)